# IIS CustErr CSS Question

Tags: css, iis-7

I'm trying to style the custom error pages in IIS7 with a linked CSS style sheet.

This works.

```
<html><head><title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<LINK href="http://stage.mysite.com/custErr/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head><body>Page Not Found</body></html>
```

I've created a virtual directory in `mysite` called `custErr` that contains the css and images needed.

But to make it easier to deploy I'd like to have it relative like this...

```
<html><head><title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<LINK href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head><body>Page Not Found</body></html>
```

After trying this I find that relative paths don't seem to work.  In fact a style sheet in the `c:\inetpub\custerr\en-US` folder doesn't work either.

Where are these pages being served from?

Is there an easier way of doing this?

So I don't have to modify each and every absolute path for each environment?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late reply but the reason why the relative paths don't work (I think) is because if you hosted a site such as www.myfavouritephotos.com and on visiting a directory on that site such as www.myfavouritephotos.com/images/  which is a directory in your website that doesn't have a default document like Default.aspx or whatever your site is set up as serving as a default page, IIS would return a HTTP Response of 404 for not finding a page to serve up or a 403 response because the user may not have the necessary rights to view the content of the directory under that url.

IIS by default would serve either the 404.htm or 403.htm file from within the c:\inetpub\custerr\en-US directory by default but when you replaced it with a custom htm file that replaces 404.htm, the relative path to the stylesheet you reference from that htm file would make a request at what the original url made to the server was so www.myfavouritephotos.com/images/(../css/style.css) which would result in an incorrect relative path so it may be able to be avoided by using a reference to a stylesheet with www.myfavouritephotos.com/css/style.css